# What does the ec2_vpc module return in Ansible

Tags: module, documentation, ansible

Ansible modules like [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html) provide a "Return Values" section in their documentation which clearly describe what values are available after you "register" the output of the command.

The [ec2_vpc module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_module.html) documentation doesn't have a "Return Values" section that I can see.

Does anyone else know where the return values for this module are documented? (Other than in the source code, which doesn't count as a proper answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure something like this out for yourself is to write a playbook like this:

```
---

- name: call ec2_vpc
  ec2_vpc: ...
  register: results

- name: display results
  debug: var=results
```

Run this with '-vvv' on the command line and you'll see everything that the module returns.

Comment: While useful, it's not clear why they don't document this... maybe I don't want to actually provision a VPC just to see how it works, eh?